# Populating a data frame with corresponding values from another

Tags: r, optimization, dataframe

I have a data frame containing values read in from an experiment with independent variables A and B which doesn't cover all possible permutations of A and B. I need to create a data frame which does contain all permutations, with zeros in those places where that particular pair of values isn't present in the data.

To create some sample data,

```
interactions <- unique(data.frame(A = sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE), 
                                  B = sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE)))
interactions <- interactions[interactions$A < interactions$B, ]
interactions$val <- runif(nrow(interactions))

possible.interactions <- data.frame(t(combn(1:5, 2)))
names(possible.interactions) <- c('A', 'B')
```

which creates

```
interactions
A B       val
1 5 0.6881106
1 2 0.5286560
2 4 0.5026426
```

and

```
possible.interactions
A B
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
2 3
2 4
2 5
3 4
3 5
4 5
```

and I want to output

```
A B  val
1 2  NA
1 3  0.5286560
1 4  NA
1 5  0.6881106
2 3  NA
2 4  0.5026426
2 5  NA
3 4  NA
3 5  NA
4 5  NA
```

What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked into `merge(x, y, all.x=T)` where `x` has all possible permutations?  `data.table` will also do it, faster, but not base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base solution that is much faster (~10x) than `merge`:

```
possible.interactions$val <- interactions$val[
  match(
    do.call(paste, possible.interactions),
    do.call(paste, interactions[1:2])
) ]
```

This produces (note, different to what you expect b/c you didn't set seed):

```
#    A B        val
# 1  1 2 0.59809242
# 2  1 3 0.92861520
# 3  1 4 0.64279549
# 4  1 5         NA
# 5  2 3 0.03554058
# 6  2 4         NA
# 7  2 5         NA
# 8  3 4         NA
# 9  3 5         NA
# 10 4 5         NA
```

This assumes A & B do not contain spaces and that `interactions` has no duplicate `A-B` pairs (will always match to first).

And the `data.table` version:

```
possible.DT <- data.table(possible.interactions)
DT <- data.table(interactions, key=c("A", "B"))
DT[possible.DT]
```

Though this is only worthwhile if your tables are large or you have uses for other benefits of `data.table`.  I've found speed to be comparable to `match` in simple cases if you include the overhead of creating and keying the tables.  I'm sure there are cases where `data.table` is much faster, especially if you key once and then use that key a lot.

For completeness, here is the `merge` version:

```
merge(possible.interactions, interactions, all.x=T)
```

Comment: +1 A bit unintuitive that match with subsetting would be faster than merge. Cool answer though.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, a part of it is that `match` will stop searching after the first match, whereas `merge` does a full scan (I believe).  But even accounting for that, it's still faster.

Answer (score 0):

If order is important to you, I recommend using `join` from the `plyr` package. As opposed to `merge` which does not provide an intuitive ordering when there are unmatched elements.

```
library(plyr)
join(interactions,possible.interactions,type="right")

Joining by: A, B
   A B         val
1  1 2          NA
2  1 3          NA
3  1 4 0.007602083
4  1 5 0.853415110
5  2 3          NA
6  2 4 0.321098658
7  2 5          NA
8  3 4          NA
9  3 5          NA
10 4 5          NA
```