# Joining to dataframes of differing length by several ID-fields in R-Statistics

Tags: r

i have a big problem. I´´m going to do calculations on data from two different dataframes  of differing length in R-statistics and with several ID-fields. But i don´t know any smart way to join these dataframes. This is an example of what i´m trying to do and how my data structures looks like:

Dataframe 1

```
  Country Village postnumber Nr.of.people.in.household

1      1   2      4000   1

2      2   2      3000   2

3      3   8      1200   1

4      4   8      1100   2
```

Dataframe2

```
   Country Village postnumber bills nr.of.bills

1       1   2      4000           1                 2

2       1   2      4000           2                 2

3       2   2      3000           1                 1

4       3   8      1200           1                 1

5       4   8      1100           1                 7

6       4   8      1100           2                 7

7       4   8      1100           3                 7

8       4   8      1100           4                 7

9       4   8      1100           5                 7

10      4   8      1100           6                 7

11      4   8      1100           7                 7
```

And i want to combine Dataframe 1 and 2 to this:
Dataframe 3

```
   People.in.household County Village postnumber bills Nr.of.bills

1                    1      1       2       4000     1           2

2                    1      1       2       4000     2           2

3                    2      2       2       3000     1           1

4                    1      3       8       1200     1           1

5                    2      4       8       1100     1           7

6                    2      4       8       1100     2           7

7                    2      4       8       1100     3           7

8                    2      4       8       1100     4           7

9                    2      4       8       1100     5           7

10                   2      4       8       1100     6           7

11                   2      4       8       1100     7           7
```

This is just an example, in reality i have so much data that it would take days to do join the dataframes together manually.

Comment: `merge(df1, df2)` will do it. for more complex merging, `plyr::join_all` is nice

Comment: Also, you can look at this **[SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756633/populating-a-data-frame-with-corresponding-values-from-another/21756945#21756945)** for some other ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, they have been very helpful, but still having problem- notice when i export my new dataframe i see that data is missing or showing different numbers than they did in R. And once again i find myself  in need of help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fast solution using `library(data.table)`:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(df1, key=c("Country", "Village", "postnumber"))
dt2 <- as.data.table(df2)
dt1[dt2]
#     Country Village postnumber Nr.of.people.in.household bills nr.of.bills
# 1:        1       2       4000                         1     1           2
# 2:        1       2       4000                         1     2           2
# 3:        2       2       3000                         2     1           1
# 4:        3       8       1200                         1     1           1
# 5:        4       8       1100                         2     1           7
# 6:        4       8       1100                         2     2           7
# 7:        4       8       1100                         2     3           7
# 8:        4       8       1100                         2     4           7
# 9:        4       8       1100                         2     5           7
# 10:       4       8       1100                         2     6           7
# 11:       4       8       1100                         2     7           7
```

`df1` holds your data frame 1, `df2` your data frame 2 accordingly.